# ZAP Scanning Jenkins Pipeline - Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled [10016] x 4 - Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-security, zap

ZAP proxy scan in our jenkins pipeline shows below WARN message.

> WARN-NEW: Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled [10016] x 4

```
http://yyyy-swagger-service.yyyy-dev.svc:8080/
http://yyyy-swagger-service.yyyy-dev.svc:8080/robots.txt
http://yyyy-swagger-service.yyyy-dev.svc:8080/sitemap.xml
http://yyyy-swagger-service.yyyy-dev.svc:8080
```

our application is a spring boot application with below security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().disable();
}
```

}

I have already tried adding below as well

```
http.headers().xssProtection()
```

Please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an out-of-date setup, plugin 10016 has been deprecated.

https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/develop/docs/scanners.md

`10016   Web Browser XSS Protection Not Enabled [Deprecated]`

The removal happened back in Feb:
https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/releases/tag/pscanrules-v27

There have been a number of rule updates since then.